# How can I simulate a super jump in Rotted Capes?

Tags: movement, rotted-capes

Reading through the *Rotted Capes* rule book, I found a few moving types, such as *tunneling*, *teleportation*, and *flight*. I also found *jumping* mentioned in surge. Aside from that side-note, I did not find anything about *jumping* at all.

How can I build a super that can leap quite far (like a frog powers-based super)? Though, using fly with a limitation that it can only be used for single moves each and only when standing on solid ground when the move starts.

**How can I best simulate a super jump power with the rules?**

Comment: **Please note this question is about a game called Rotted Capes.** We have had three answers deleted already because the authors thought this was a question about D&D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Surge allows you to make super jumps.**

See p69 of Rotted Capes.

> Surge
> Primary Attribute: Quickness
> Burnout: 5
> You are capable of incredible bursts of speed.
> Effect: When you acquire this power you must choose a mode
> of movement: flying, jumping, running, or swimming.
> A number of times per scene equal to your power’s
> passive modifier, you may increase your Pace by your power
> ranks when utilizing your chosen mode of movement.
> Special (Restriction): This power does not grant the ability to
> fly, only gives you a boost of speed while flying if your chosen
> mode of movement is flight.

You jump with Athletics. (p39)

> Athletics
> Primary Attribute: Vigor
> You excel at physical feats of strength and endurance.
> You are adept at sustained activity. When Climbing, Jumping,
> or Swimming, the Editor-in-Chief determines the Difficulty.
> Success allows you to move at half Pace. A running jump
> allows you to clear your passive Quickness or Might modifier.
> A Routine (TN: 15) Athletics Action Skill Roll allows you to
> deliberately fall 10 feet without injury.
> At the Editor-in-Chief’s discretion, Athletics can be used
> to push past your limits, grab something that’s just out of
> reach, or other athletic feats.
> Focus: Climbing, Running, Jumping, Swimming, Feats of
> Strengths.

You'll need the transporter archetype, and lots of quickness to fund big hops. You'll have an advantage in areas with lots of height, since you can jump high to avoid zombies and to plink them from range. Your two main stats are quickness and vigor. Quickness is good for stealth, ranged attacks, driving, and acrobatics, so those are good areas to focus on, with vigor being good for enduring immense amounts of damage.

If you want a secondary power, armor, bestial transformation, celerity, elasticity, energy blast, invulnrability, regeneration, shapeshifting, resistance, and speed work with your two primary attributes. There's a lot of ways you can go as a super jumper, depending on what skills or powers you want to emphasize.

I would also recommend asking your table about fluffing normal movement as jumping. It doesn't change balance if when you are 'running' you are actually jumping along the ground.